# How to deal with lots of different customizations in a code base?

Tags: customization, code-organization, modularity

We created a web app that we use for a SaaS business. Simple customizations can be done through CSS overwrites and even simple plugins.

However, we have a number of bigger "enterprise" customers with "enterprise" demand for customization. These customizations include changes to the UI, new screens, different screenflows, different backends, new features that will never go into the main app, new features that may go into the main app in the future and so and so forth.

For those kind of bigger changes to the app we maintain forks per customer. In the fork we just change things as we need. The codebases keep on diverging and we merge and cherry-pick things from master to keep them up to date with important stuff that happens in the main development tree.

It works but we all wonder how well it will scale in the long term. I wonder what would be the best way to handle such customers with a high demand for customization.

I see three options.

**Extreme Modularization**

This is for instance what the [atom editor](https://atom.io) does. Nearly everything in atom is done through a plugin and well defined interfaces.

The benefit of that is that customizations can be done very isolated. You don't need a big fork but rather multiple smaller sub components need forking and then you assemble it together via a different `package.json`.

This comes with the downside of complexity. Especially when it comes to UI stuff you need to have solid interfaces with good hooks to build up on. I wonder if what works for Atom, works for any complex UI. And after all, Github doesn't face the challenge of having to maintain lots of different versions of atom customized for different customers. Would they actually be in a better position? In the end it probably comes down to maintaining plenty of forks instead of just a couple of ones.

**Git branches**

This is what we do today. Branch, rebase, merge, cherry-pick just let Git do the grunt work and pray for things not to diverge too much.

**Feature flags**

I'm quite torn on this one. Many companies from GitHub to FlickR use feature flags extensively. [asana also mentioned](https://blog.asana.com/2011/04/using-flags-to-ease-new-feature-development/#) that they use them to roll out features only to a subset of customers. In theory it sounds quite good if we could just hide all customizations behind feature flags and leave peaceful and in harmony with one common code base. We can even make sure that unused features are striped out from the final compilation. This is what EmberJS does, too.

But [others warn](http://java.dzone.com/articles/feature-toggles-are-one-worst) that feature flags are really really bad for maintainability in the long run and should be used only as a temporally tool until the feature finally proves stable. If we would use feature flags to hide customizations we would have to maintain them for a long time.

How would you tackle this problem?

Comment: I think this belongs to [programmers.se] instead.

Comment: Happy to have it migrated if it get's more attention there :)